# Sign in Configuration Issue in release version of App

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have this app which uses Google Services json file configured with a SHA1 of a debug key, and then build the Signed Build with a new key and used that `release.apk` to install the app. But the sign in part isn't working now in the release version of the app.

So now my question is, should the Google services json file be configured using the SHA1 of the signed key?? Ignore the formatting since I'm using this from mobile.

Comment: Has your applicationId (com.example...) changed?

Comment: No. Everything is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the document: Setting Up Google Play Games Services

### Specify client ID settings

> You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint. Make sure to use the same package name for both. This allows Google Play games services to recognize calls from your linked APKs that are signed with either certificate. For more information about certificate signing for Android, see [Signing Your Application](https://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

Check this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24390135/5995040), it talked about the difference of the clientID for debug and release version. Lastly, check the documents : [Prepare for Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html) and [Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for a detailed instruction of preparing your app for release.

Comment: Thank You, I managed to overcome that by adding the SHA-1 of my release version key to my current google services portal thing and downloaded the updated json file. Username checks out though ;)